# DatePicker Control in IOS with large Daterange

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am looking for a Date Picker control to choose a date between 10'000 B.C. till today (2015). Can I use the `UIDatePicker` for that ( I didn't find any information with [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minimumDate) ?

I mean does it allow a date range of 12015 years ? Or is there another way to achieve this with standard controls ? or Do I have to create my own control ?

Comment: If all you need is a year (without month and day) then the easiest way to do that would be to use `UIPickerView`.

Comment: Do you need only the year or also the month, day and time?

Comment: I need year and month if possible. Eventually I could also live with years only.

Comment: @Artrmz: Thanks for the hint with UIPickerView. I guess I will try it.

Comment: @mcfly soft Actually a month is quite easy to add to that view as well. Day is a bit catchy because of how day's number depends on month :)

Comment: @Artrmz: I see thanks. I guess that is the solution. I will simply add my own calculated values to a UIPIckerView like "1492 December" for example. right?

Comment: @mcfly soft You can split it into 2 components - one for month and second for year which you'll popualte with prepared arrays with whatever values you want to show.

Comment: @Artrmz: Thanks for the answer. Perfect. This will solve also another problem for me. I could have 5 components. 1. Thousand-Value 2. Hundred-Value 3. Decade-Value 4. Singleyear Value 5. Month. You can Answer like this if you like and I will accept.

Comment: @mcfly soft Added :) Let me know if you need any more help with `UIPickerView` in the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html) and set (`UIPickerViewDelegate` delegate methods)

`- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView`

to whatever number you want - ie. 2 if you want to be able to choose a month and a year. Then you can set how many values should be in each component by setting up

`- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component`

and then populate it with your arrays

`- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`

or (if you want to customize it a bit more)

`- (UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView*)view`

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `maximumDate`, `minimumDate` property in `UIDatePicker`

Note: `NSDate` models the change from the **Julian** to the **Gregorian** calendar in **October 1582**, and calendrical calculations performed in conjunction with `NSCalendar` take this transition into account. Note, however, that some locales adopted the Gregorian calendar at other times; for example, Great Britain didn't switch over until September 1752 [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDate)

Comment: I already saw that I could set the maximumDate and minimumDate. The Question is what is the lowest possible minimumDate ? I asked if it is possible to display the range between 10.000 BC and today.